# How to set state with React hooks from async fucntion return

Tags: reactjs, flask, promise, async-await, react-hooks

I have a React module that makes a call to a function from an API in another JS module it imports. This function makes an async call to a flask route in my backend which returns a JSON object.

setSearchData is a useState.

In my React app, I setSearchData(getData(searchTerm)) with the expectation that the getData(searchTerm) function will asynchronously return something. When my promsie is resolved it should pipe jason data as such:

flask route -> searchAPI async func -> exported API func -> setState via hook

getsearch(search_term) -> flaskRoute(route, searchTerm) -> getSearchData(searchTerm) -> setSearchData( getSearchData(searchTerm) )

This doesn't work of course. The JSON data does get returned but it never updates the state. It seems as if the state gets updated with `null` and doesn't wait for the promise to get resolved.

How can I get an async function to play nice with React state which is itself async?

api_flask_routes.py

```
from flask import jsonify, request

@bp.route('/search/<search_term>', methods=['GET'])
def getsearch(search_term):
    search_data = [
        ['stuff'],
        ['stuff'],
        ['stuff'],
        ...
    ]
    return jsonify(search_data)
```

SearchDataAPI.js

```
async function regularRoute({ route, searchTerm = '', method = 'GET' }) {
    const routeWithSearchTerm = `${route}/${searchTerm}`;
    const endpoint = `${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}${searchTerm ? routeWithSearchTerm : route}`;
    const configs = {
        method,
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    };

    return fetch(endpoint, configs)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .catch((err) =>  console.error(err));
}

function getSearchData(searchTerm) {
   return flaskRoute("/api/search/", searchTerm); // returns json to importing module
}
```

MySearch.js  this is a React component

```
import searchDataAPI from '../searchAPI/SearchDataAPI';

//// DATA RETRIEVAL FROM BACKEND ////
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState(null);
const getSearchData = searchDataAPI.searchFunctions.getSearchData;

function handleSubmitSearch(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (searchTerm.trim().length > 0) {
      setSearchData(null); // clears out previous search data
      setSearchData(getSearchData(searchTerm)); // this doesn't work!
      // more stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for your function resolve by using .then() like the following :

```
 getSearchData(searchTerm).then(result => {
    setSearchData(result)
});
```

if it still return null, then you have to change your getSearchData() to async, so it can also return the resolve result like :

```
async function getSearchData(searchTerm) {
   return await flaskRoute("/api/search/", searchTerm).then(res => {
    return res;
  });
}
```

if that also doesn't work, you can directly setState inside getSearchData() like :

```
function getSearchData(searchTerm) {
   flaskRoute("/api/search/", searchTerm).then(result => {
     setSearchData(result);
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So in my React component, MySearch.js, refactor into Promise format?

 getSearchData(searchTerm).then(result => {
    setSearchData(result)
});

Comment: exactly, try all of them and use the one that fits the best for you.

Comment: The above method didn't work. Setting state inside SearchDataAPI.js DOES work. However, that makes my code less orthogonal I don't like setting state in a React mode inside of a different non-React module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use an asynchronous function in the file that has the React useState/setState function and any other function in between. Keep in mind that the useState hook is asynchronous itself.

```
async function regularRoute({ route, searchTerm = '', method = 'GET' }) {
    const routeWithSearchTerm = `${route}/${searchTerm}`;
    const endpoint = `${HOST_IP_ADDRESS}${routeWithSearchTerm}`;
    const configs = {
        method,
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    };

    return fetch(endpoint, configs)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .catch((err) =>  console.error(err));
}

async function getSearchData(searchTerm) {
   const data = await flaskRoute('/api/search/', searchTerm);
   return data;
}
```

Then in my React file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [data, setData] = useState('');

async function handleClick(e, searchTerm) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newData = await getSearchData(searchTerm);
    setData(newData);
};
```

Done.